# How to transfrom dataframe column to lines?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A =   ID Material1 Materia2 material3 
      24   1        0        0 
      12   1        1        0
      24   0        0        2
```

I want to have all information in one column like this:

```
A =   ID  Materials
      24   Material1
      12   Material1 
      12   Material2
      24   Material3 
      24   Material3
```

Do I have to save the same occurence of materials, does anyone know how to do it please?

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of repeat:

```
s = df.set_index('ID').stack()
s.repeat(s).reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ID    level_1
0  24  Material1
1  12  Material1
2  12   Materia2
3  24  material3
4  24  material3
```

Comment: `df.set_index...`, try replace it with your actual dataframe variable. Otherwise, you should indicate what doesn't work.

Comment: the second line of the code doesnt work i get the error : ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'NO'

Comment: It isn’t the code that is not working. Your data is not clean, it contains a non- numerical value `NO`. What do you want to do with it?